# Azure Service Fabric Cluster Update

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a cluster in Azure and it failed to update automatically so I'm trying a manual update.  I tried via the portal, it failed so I kicked off an update using PS, it failed also.  The update starts then just sits at "UpdatingUserConfiguration" then after an hour or so fails with a time out.  I have removed all application types and check my certs for "NETWORK SERVCIE".  The cluster is 5 VM single node type, Windows.

Error

> Set-AzureRmServiceFabricUpgradeType : Code: ClusterUpgradeFailed,
>   Message: Cluster upgrade failed. Reason  Code: 'UpgradeDomainTimeout',
>   Upgrade Progress:
>   '{"upgradeDescription":{"targetCodeVersion":"6.0.219.9494"," 
>   targetConfigVersion":"1","upgradePolicyDescription":{"upgradeMode":"UnmonitoredAuto","forceRestart":false,"u
>   pgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeout":"37201.09:59:01","kind":"Rolling"}},"targetCodeVersion":"6.0.219.9494","target
>   ConfigVersion":"1","upgradeState":"RollingBackCompleted","upgradeDomains":[{"name":"1","state":"Completed"},
>   {"name":"2","state":"Completed"},{"name":"3","state":"Completed"},{"name":"4","state":"Completed"}],"rolling
>   UpgradeMode":"UnmonitoredAuto","upgradeDuration":"02:02:07","currentUpgradeDomainDuration":"00:00:00","unhea
>   lthyEvaluations":[],"currentUpgradeDomainProgress":{"upgradeDomainName":"","nodeProgressList":[]},"startTime
>   stampUtc":"2018-05-17T03:13:16.4152077Z","failureTimestampUtc":"2018-05-17T05:13:23.574452Z","failureReason"
>   :"UpgradeDomainTimeout","upgradeDomainProgressAtFailure":{"upgradeDomainName":"1","nodeProgressList":[{"node
>   Name":"_mstarsf10_1","upgradePhase":"PreUpgradeSafetyCheck","pendingSafetyChecks":[{"kind":"EnsureSeedNodeQu
>   orum"}]}]}}'.

Any ideas on what I can do about a "EnsureSeedNodeQuorum" error ?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause was only 3 seed nodes in the cluster as a result of the cluster being build with a VM scale set that had "overprovision" set to true.  Lesson learned, remember to set "overprovision" to false.
I ended up deleting the cluster and scale set and recreated using my stored ARM template.